# css slider full width

Tags: html, css

I am building this website for a friend of mine. She asked if i could make a slider of the header pics. I have tryd making it full width but it looks different in firefox and chrome and i dont know why.

the url is xx

The problem is that in firefox it has a margin/padding left of a lot, instead of 0. Tried adding !important, but no difference. In chrome it is nearly full width, but still not totally. I think im looking over something obvious :( help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you created a `row` as a container of the slider only. The `row` adds `margin-left: -25px` and  `margin-right: -25px`. If you wanna use such a structure, you should put a `col-xs-12` (if you're using Bootstrap 4 use `col-12`) inside `row`.
After that, you will see a fullwidth slider. 
As a consequence your structure will be like that:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            ...
            slider structure
            ...

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should fix your problem in Firefox too.

Comment: Okay, so now ive got another issue. I got the slider full width, but i cant get the whole of it to be full width. Dont know why. highly appreciate the effort for the width fix

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don’t understand your last issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you defined the width of the parent element carousel-example correct. You can extend your bootstrap.css for .carousel with the full width:

```
.carousel {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

BR

webbolle